# cmake doesn't recognize dependency on static lz4

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

I'm trying to link against a statically built lz4. As an example I'm using a hello world project

```
$ tree hello-world/
hello-world/
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── main.cpp

0 directories, 2 files

$ cat main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}

$ cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12.2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
project(hello-world)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

include(FetchContent)

# ================ lz4 ================
option(LZ4_BUILD_CLI "Build lz4 program" OFF)
option(LZ4_BUILD_LEGACY_LZ4C "Build lz4c progam with legacy argument support" OFF)
# Per lz4 documentation, https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/d44371841a2f1728a3f36839fd4b7e872d0927d3/build/cmake/CMakeLists.txt#L39,
# need to set LZ4_BUNDLED_MODE to anything but empty string
set(LZ4_BUNDLED_MODE "ON")

set(LZ4_REPO "https://github.com/lz4/lz4")
set(LZ4_REPO_TAG "v1.9.3")
message(STATUS "Fetching ${LZ4_REPO} ${LZ4_REPO_TAG}")
FetchContent_Declare(
    lz4
    GIT_REPOSITORY ${LZ4_REPO}
    GIT_TAG        ${LZ4_REPO_TAG}
    )

FetchContent_GetProperties(lz4)
if(NOT lz4_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(lz4)

    message(STATUS "running body")
    add_subdirectory(${lz4_SOURCE_DIR}/build/cmake ${lz4_BINARY_DIR})
    include_directories(${lz4_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
endif()
set(LZ4_STATIC_LIBRARY "${lz4_BINARY_DIR}/liblz4.a")
message(STATUS ${lz4_SOURCE_DIR})
message(STATUS ${lz4_BINARY_DIR})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LZ4_STATIC_LIBRARY})
```

Here is what I'm getting when I build and compile the project

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Fetching https://github.com/lz4/lz4 v1.9.3
-- running body
CMake Deprecation Warning at build/_deps/lz4-src/build/cmake/CMakeLists.txt:37 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wall
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wall - Success
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wextra
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wextra - Success
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wundef
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wundef - Success
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wcast_qual
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wcast_qual - Success
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wcast_align
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wcast_align - Success
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wshadow
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wshadow - Success
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wswitch_enum
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wswitch_enum - Success
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wdeclaration_after_statement
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wdeclaration_after_statement - Success
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wstrict_prototypes
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wstrict_prototypes - Success
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wpointer_arith
-- Performing Test CFLAG_Wpointer_arith - Success
-- Performing Test CFLAG_W4
-- Performing Test CFLAG_W4 - Failed
-- /tmp/hello-world/build/_deps/lz4-src
-- /tmp/hello-world/build/_deps/lz4-build
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /tmp/hello-world/build
$ make
/opt/cmake-3.19.5-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -S/tmp/hello-world -B/tmp/hello-world/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/opt/cmake-3.19.5-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /tmp/hello-world/build/CMakeFiles /tmp/hello-world/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/hello-world/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/hello-world/build'
cd /tmp/hello-world/build && /opt/cmake-3.19.5-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /tmp/hello-world /tmp/hello-world /tmp/hello-world/build /tmp/hello-world/build /tmp/hello-world/build/CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target hello-world
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/hello-world/build'
make  -f CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/hello-world/build'
[ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++  -I/tmp/hello-world/build/_deps/lz4-src/lib -std=c++17 -o CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/main.cpp.o -c /tmp/hello-world/main.cpp
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '_deps/lz4-build/liblz4.a', needed by 'hello-world'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/hello-world/build'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:118: CMakeFiles/hello-world.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/hello-world/build'
make: *** [Makefile:106: all] Error 2
```

I thought because of `add_subdirectory(${lz4_SOURCE_DIR}/build/cmake ${lz4_BINARY_DIR})` it should be working, however clearly that's not the case. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the body of that if being run?

Comment: @Shawn can you clarify what do you mean? I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Is `NOT lz4_POPULATED` true or false? Is the stuff in that if being run or is it being skipped?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, it is being run

Comment: `FetchContent` builds external library **with** your project, not *before* it. So for link with that library you need to use not the name of its *file*, which is not yet created, but its **target** name, which CMake is aware of. The correct name of the library target you could find in the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/lz4/lz4/blob/d44371841a2f1728a3f36839fd4b7e872d0927d3/build/cmake/CMakeLists.txt#L117) for that library. `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} lz4_static)`.